# NaN in C++ why?

Tags: c++, classification, nan, knn

I'm trying to implement a K-nn classifier. A part of this problem is getting the euclidean distance from an example to another one. I'm having problems calculating it, because `sum` finally is NaN.

The problem is in this code block:

```
for(int i=0;i<fdataset.size();i++){
  float sum=0;
  for(int k=0;k<fdataset[i].size();k++){
    if(mask[k]){
      sum+=(fdataset[i][k]-example[k])*(fdataset[i][k]-example[k]);
    }
  }
  results[i]=sqrt(sum);
}
```

`fdataset` is a `vector< vector<float> >` and `example` is `vector<float>`. There should be no problems. So, why I'm having this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: "If the argument is less than -0, FE_INVALID is raised and NaN is returned." from [`std::sqrt`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt)

Comment: @Maikel when can `sum` be negative? `(fdataset[i][k]-example[k])*(fdataset[i][k]-example[k])` is always positive or `0`

Comment: Is sum NaN or does results contain NaN?

Comment: Check if fdataset contains `NaN` or if `example` contains `NaN`.

Comment: What are the datatypes of example and fdataset?

Comment: @Maikel OP mentioned them, but however posting a [MCVE] would improve the question a lot.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's extremely unlikely that you get NaN for any OTHER reason than "bad inputs somewhere". With incomplete code & data, it's impossible for anyone here to say what that somewhere is - but it's unlikely you've found a compiler or hardware bug, I'd say.

Comment: The sensible way to approach this is to find out where the NaN comes from. We can't do it based on what you show us here. Try debugging with debugger or with help of debug prints, or provide a MVCE.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for your responses. I've found how to fix my problem but I need to know how to compare if my value is nan or -nan. I can assign min or max values if the value is -nan or nan respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your data set is "poisoned" with one or more NaNs. It would only take a single NaN in the `fdataset` or `example` arrays to corrupt `sum`.

As an aid to debugging, you could check each input with `std::isnan()`.

**Update:** As user akavel suggested in a comment, there are other expressions that can also generate NaN in IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic. [Wikipedia lists them here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN). I believe that the operations relevant to your code are:

- Operations where one of the operands is a NaN
- `0 * inf`
- `inf - inf`

So you should also check that your inputs are not `inf` with `std::isinf()`.

Comment: Also, if some values overflow float they could apparently [become INF](http://www.cquestions.com/2011/02/float-overflow-in-c.html), and INF-INF is NaN I think

Comment: A personal favorite for data cleaning is `std::isfinite()` which returns false for NaNs and infinities.